# initializing arrays in sh

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sh

I want to initialize an array in sh.

In bash that would be:

```
list=(`seq 1 4`)
```

In sh I try to do it like this:

```
    for i in `seq 1 4`; do
        list[$((i-1))]="$i"
    done
```

I get an error though for each iteration saying:

```
list[0]=1: not found
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499486/how-to-mark-an-array-in-posix-sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[POSIX sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02) doesn't support arrays.  You need a more advanced shell for that, e.g. `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh`.

Comment: Not really.  It just fails to mention that only some shells support it.

Comment: `sh on OSX` seems to support arrays.

Comment: Only because `sh` on OS X is really `bash`, which is a bit loose about what it accepts in "POSIX" mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use arrays, you can fudge them by writing your own array function. I'm not going to encourage this by giving you a full function :-) but here's the gist:

```
$ f0=yay 
$ t=0
$ eval echo f$t
f0
$ eval echo \$f$t
yay
```