# Shell script syntax error when run with sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I have written a little script. When it is finished, it will set the environment variables I need and start a Node server for me. I made the script so that I have a command line interface to change the environment variables on startup without having to remember.

This is what I have so far...

```
if [ $1 = "d" ] || [ $1 = "default" ]
    then
        export PORT=80
        export ENV=development
        export ENDPOINT=development
    elif [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
        printf "\n\n-------------------\n\nPort Options:\n[1] 80\n[2] 3000\n[3] Custom\n\n-------------------\n\n"
        read -p "Select Option: " PORT_OPTION
        if [ "$PORT_OPTION" -eq 1 ]
            then 
                REQUESTED_PORT=80
            elif [ "$PORT_OPTION" -eq 2 ]
                then
                    REQUESTED_PORT=3000
            elif [ "$PORT_OPTION" -eq 3 ]
                then
                    read -p "Enter Requested Port Number: " REQUESTED_PORT
            else
                echo "Invalid slection...exiting."
                exit
        fi
        if [ "$REQUESTED_PORT" -eq "$REQUESTED_PORT" 2> /dev/null ]
            then
                if [ "$REQUESTED_PORT" -lt 1024 ] && [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]
                    then
                        echo "Must have Root authoritzation to use this port...exiting."
                        exit
                    else
                        if netstat -an | grep "$REQUESTED_PORT" > /dev/null
                            then
                                SERVICE_PIDS_STRING=`lsof -i tcp:$REQUESTED_PORT -t`
                                OLD_IFS="$IFS"
                                IFS='
                                '
                                SERVICE_PIDS=($SERVICE_PIDS_STRING)
                                IFS="$OLD_IFS"
                                printf 'Port is in use by the following service(s)...\n\n-------------------\n\nProcess : PID\n'
                                for PID in "${SERVICE_PIDS[@]}"
                                    do
                                        PROCESS_NAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm=`
                                        printf "$PROCESS_NAME : $PID\n"
                                    done
                                printf "\n-------------------\n\nPlease kill the procceses utilizing port $REQUESTED_PORT and run this script again...exiting."
                                exit
                            else
                                echo "NOTHING USING PORT"
                        fi
                fi
            else
                echo "Invalid port number...exiting."
                exit
        fi
    else
         echo "Invalid argument...exiting." 
         exit
fi
```

I have searched around for a while trying to find a solution to my problem. previously line #37 was changed from `read -a SERVICE_PIDS <<< "${SERVICE_PIDS_STRING}"`. Everything works well, and both versions of line #37 have worked for me...unless I'm running the script as sudo.

This wouldn't be a problem, but the system protects certain ports, so sometimes I need to use sudo on the script.

I'm receiving the following error when I run my script with sudo...

```
./Start.sh: 36: ./Start.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Why does using sudo break my script, and how can I remedy this issue?

P.S. I would prefer to get this working with Shell Script rather than Bash. (I may be saying the wrong thing here, but my understanding is that if I use pure Shell Script the script can be run from any UNIX system, and my partner uses a Mac.)

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arrays. If you want to use arrays, use bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark an array in posix sh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499486/how-to-mark-an-array-in-posix-sh)

Comment: The default shell in OS X is currently bash 3.2