# Bash commands in C code

Tags: c, bash

I am trying to run some bash commands using **C** program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int j;
    char a[4]={'a','9','8','4'};
    for (j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=%c      %p\n",j,a[j],&a[j]);
    }
    system("a=(a 9 8 4)");
    system("echo ${a[*]}");
}
```

In above code, below lines do not show anything

```
system("a=(a 9 8 4)");
system("echo ${a[*]}");
```

Any idea?

Comment: system("a=(a 9 8 4) ; echo ${a[*]}")

Comment: Hmm... why call bash? Most bash commands are implemented in C and you can call them directly using the C API...

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

- each time you call `system()` a new shell will be invoked. That means variable declarations will only be visible to the currently invoked shell, not in subsequent calls to `system()`
- besides that, `system()` internally calls `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. `/bin/sh` is on many systems (like yours) a link to a POSIX compliant shell. [Array definitions are unfortunately not part of the POSIX shell language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499486/how-to-mark-an-array-in-posix-sh).

Answer (score 3):

`system` usually runs a POSIX shell (often dash, not bash) and each invocation starts a new shell process, so if you really want to start bash from `system` and have the second bash command print the array defined in the first, you need something like `system("bash -c 'a=(a 9 8 4); echo ${a[*]}'");`.